# Are there any SVN servers written in PHP?

Tags: php, svn

Given that SVN repos can be accessed over HTTP, would it be possible to code an SVN server in PHP?

Has anyone done this?

Comment: This is akin to asking, "Can I write a web server in PHP?" The answer, then is "WHY?!"

Comment: Err.. why would someone want to do that?

Comment: I want to run an SVN server on a shared hosting package.

Comment: Just switch hosts. (Please)

Comment: hehe, maybe not, but look for some written in JavaScript, there is almost everything not suitable to write in JavaScript actually written in that language:)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the SVN Pecl extension:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

This is **not** an SVN server written in PHP though, but a client API that interfaces **with** a server.

Like everyone else, I too find it rather ... *odd* to want to write a PHP SVN Server, which probably takes quite an effort and time, when all you have to do is just to switch hosts. As an alternative, use an open SVN hosting service and checkout from your hosting service with Phing or something when needed.

Comment: Ya, I'm beginning to think this is the route to take.

Comment: Not odd at all if your hosting provider doesn't provide SVN unless you take the (very expensive) VPH option.

Answer (score 1):

There are no SVN servers written in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Found that: [PHPVC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvc/) on sourceforge, it's not SVN but it is a version control completely written in PHP and it don't use SQL, just plain file.

From the SF page:

> phpEasyVCS is a simple version control system (VCS) with minimal hosting requirements, namely PHP 5.2+. No database is needed. Files can be viewed and uploaded with a browser or by WebDAV. It is very easy to view the file versions at a specific point in time.

It's not SVN, but it might be usefull.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean a PHP front-end to a repository? If so, look no further than [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Comment: Trac is written in Python, not PHP.

Comment: No, not a front-end. See my comment above.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Slip of the brain. Seems all the well known front ends are in python (trac, gitosis, etc).